# Greece Residence / SA Passport / Rep Ireland Visitation

Tags: visas, europe, ireland, greece, residency

I have a residence status from Greece but have a South African Passport.  May I go to Rep Of Ireland without my spouse?

Comment: For what purpose would your travel be? Tourism, immigration, other?

Comment: Also, do you have "Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen” issued, by any country, under 10 of Directive 2004/38/EC (the “Free Movement Directive”)?

Comment: @CGCampbell a residence card issued on the basis of the traveler's relationship with the spouse would not have any more effect than any Schengen residence permit since the trip is being made without the spouse.

Answer (score 7):

If you are traveling alone, being a resident in Greece doesn't exempt you from any visa requirement in Ireland. To the extent that a visa is required for your specific circumstances (citizenship, purpose and length of the trip), you will need to obtain one regardless. South African citizens do need a visa, even for a short tourism visit.

Since you mention your spouse, I suspect you might reside in Greece as the spouse of an EU (Irish?) citizen. If you have a residence card as a member of an Union Citizen's family (it should say so on the card) ***and*** you are traveling with them or joining them, you would indeed be exempted from any visa requirement. Since you are traveling without your spouse, this exemption doesn't apply here.